# how to determine if 2 line graphs with different values are same

Tags: database, hadoop, math, graph, bigdata

I'm trying to compare line graphs with completely different values and scale.
On X-axis i have values from 0-30 (Days) and on Y-axis i have stock values.

My task is to compare the data of last 30 days with a huge database which already contains different stock values.

is there any way to compare the shape to 2 graphs irrespective of what values were used in y-axis?

Thanks in advance
[First Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjGnu.png)
[Second Garph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPQ7K.png)

Comment: uhm... your first and second graphs are identical.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i have edited my post

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood and you mean something more sophisticated, but you could scale each data set down by finding the min/max values and do something like `data_new = (data_old - min) / (max - min)` to get a normalized range between 0 and 1, then compare their shapes.

Comment: Well, it depends on how exactly you want to *compare* them. If you just want to compare their shapes, then spug's idea will work. If you are comparing their actual values, then you don't want to do any rescaling at all. What do you mean by *compare*?

Comment: Check [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence).